# Apache HTTP Server: How to restrict access to directory listings to some ip ranges?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

In Apache HTTP Server 2.4: How to restrict access to directory listings to some ip ranges? Files should be still publicly downloadable over URLs but directory listings should be restricted.

Comment: is it an option to block the index pages for a range of ip's?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is possible with [`<If>` Expression](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html).

This is your vhost/conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        Options -Indexes        # disable listing
        <If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} == '10.0.0.5'">
            Options +Indexes    # enable listing if ip matches
        </If>
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/html>
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Tested it with Ubuntu Server and Windows with Apache 2.4 – sadly this won't work with older Apache versions.

---

For IP ranges it is possible to use another way to check the IP:

```
<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} -ipmatch '10.0.0.0/8'">
```

or faster way is with `-R`:

```
<If "-R '192.168.0.0/16' || -R '10.0.248.0/24'">
```

Comment: Thanks for that bounty and for that tip with `-R` - the docs says it's also more efficient.